# How can I make lists of files, each list containing 10 files, total number of files is 1330?

Tags: python

Have a look at figures, [image], as you can see, I am using glob to load the data and storing in files

What I want to do is I want to take ten files and do some operation and I will get the one file output from that thus I will have a total of 133 output files.

The manual option I tried
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of how I would do it.

```
# Creating the list example
a = list(range(1330))
# new empty list
b = list()

for i in range(0, len(a), 10):
    b.append(a[i:i+10])
```

Essentially using the steps within the range function we can step over the 10 selected and collect the next 10 items in the list